# How to convert UTF8 general in UTF8 unicode?

Tags: mysql, collation, utf-8

**Short:**
My tables have the collation `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`, but the data itself is `utf8mb4_general_ci` and now I like to know how I can convert it into unicode?

**Long:**
I used this query to convert all my latin tables to utf8:

```
ALTER TABLE ' . $table_name . ' CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
```

Then I reminded a security hole in wordpress regarding truncated blog comments through bypassing the 3 bytes limit and I decided to convert all tables to `utf8mb4`:

```
ALTER TABLE ' . $table_name . ' CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Everything seemed to work, but after a while I received through my own security check, that some content has been truncated:

```
Before:
Also mit Nummer/Abe?
Was wird�&euro;�s denn?
ISO-8859-1

After:
Also mit Nummer/Abe?
Was wird
UTF-8
```

As you can see someone was able to send a latin/iso quotation mark and mysql truncated the string.

So I checked my mysql collaction settings:

```
SHOW variables WHERE variable_name LIKE '%coll%' OR variable_name LIKE '%char%'
```

Result:

```
character_set_client: utf8mb4
character_set_connection: utf8mb4
character_set_database: utf8mb4
character_set_filesystem: binary
character_set_results: utf8mb4
character_set_server: latin1
character_set_system: utf8
character_sets_dir: /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
collation_connection: utf8mb4_general_ci
collation_database: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
collation_server: latin1_swedish_ci
```

As I'm not able to change server collations I asked my hosting company and they said:

> Settings on the server will be overwritten by your database settings,
>   so no change is necessary. But you should set
>   `collation_connection` and `collation_database` to the same value.

I tested a little bit around and found out that this sets `collation_connection` to `utf8mb4_general_ci`:

```
mysqli_set_charset('utf8mb4', $this->db_connect_id);
```

And if I use this instead, it sets it to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`:

```
mysql_query('SET collation_connection = @@collation_database;');
```

Now I could use this setting, but then all existing special chars are scrambled. Only new posts will be saved and displayed correctly. This means my tables have the correct `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` collation, but the data itself seems to be formatted as `utf8mb4_general_ci`. I do not know why, maybe because the connection itself while calling `CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET` was set to `utf8mb4_general_ci`?!

Anyway... So how can I solve this issue? How can I convert the `utf8mb4_general_ci` data into `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` so I'm able to use `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` as `collation_connection`?

Comment: I don#t know of ot os too late. But you should have two databases on the same server, one with the old charset and one with the new inclusive all tables, with he right and then you connect to the databases with the correct charset in the connection string and transfer so the data.

Comment: mgutt: something doesn't seem right about this description. Not sure what you mean by "_the data itself is `utf8mb4_general_ci`_". Do you mean the connection collation? Because the data in the table _is_ `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`, and both of those collations (as well as any `utf8*`, `utf16*`, or `utf32*` collation), are Unicode. The "utf" prefix means Unicode. The "unicode" vs "general" part of the collation name refers to the _sorting_, not the encoding of the characters. Meaning, there should be _no_ difference between `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` and `utf8mb4_general_ci` in terms of storing characters.

Comment: Also, you said you first converted to `utf8` before `utf8mb4`. Did you check all of the data after the initial convert to `utf8`? All characters that work in `utf8` should also work in `utf8mb4`. Is it possible the truncation happened in the initial convert to `utf8` that wasn't notice until after the second convert? Also, can you check the actual bytes of that truncated value to see if there aren't additional characters being hidden by a `\x00` null string terminator? Not sure how MySQL handles displaying those, but SQL Server won't show anything after a `\x00` even though the data is there.

Comment: See this for black diamonds:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Comment: A _character set_ (latin1 / utf8 / utf8mb4) determines the encoding.  The _collation_ determines the sort order.